# Emberjs: Uncaught Error: No route matched the URL ''

Tags: ember.js

I upgrade from ember rc1 to rc3. Now I'm receiving "Uncaught Error: No route matched the URL'' " when navigating to localhost root. My relevant router code (pretty standard) is below. Did something change with the router from rc1 to rc3? I couldn't find any changes in the documentation to indicate what might be wrong. Thanks for any help.

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route 'index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the index route from your router map.

```
App.Router.map(function (){ });
```

Comment: what black magic is this. am i reading documentation wrong or does it need to be updated? thanks for the help!